# what is an ambigous type in the context with the function?

Tags: haskell

I am reading the following [doc](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/mark-jones/fundeps.ps) about functional dependencies. On the page 5, it describes the ambiguous type:

> First, the empty function has an ambiguous type:
>
> ```
> empty :: Collects e ce ⇒ ce.
> ```
>
> By ‘ambiguous’ we mean that there is a type variable e that appears on
>   the left of the ⇒ symbol, but not on the right. The problem with this
>   is that, according to the theoretical foundations of Haskell
>   overloading, we cannot guarantee a well- defined semantics for any
>   term with an ambiguous type [2, 4]. For this reason, a Haskell system
>   will reject any attempt to define or use such terms.

I have a few questions:

1. What is exactly an ambiguous type?
2. What does the author mean with `we cannot guarantee a well- defined 
   semantics for any term with an ambiguous type`, that is influence by an ambiguous type.

Comment: The definition of ambiguous type is practically staring you in the nose there. It's a type with a variable that appears on the left of an `=>` but not on the right. Just spell the sentence in this order instead: "By ‘ambiguous’ we mean that there is a type variable that appears on the left of the ⇒ symbol, but not on the right (and in the example above that variable is named e)."

Comment: What does the sentence `The problem with this is that, according to the theoretical foundations of Haskell overloading, we cannot guarantee a well- defined semantics for any term with an ambiguous type [2, 4].` mean?

Comment: "Ambiguous" just means we don't know what `e` represents. If we don't know what `e` means, we can't know what `empty` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as other pointed out we don't know the `e` variable because it only appears on the left:

```
empty :: Collects e ce ⇒ ce
```

Let's suppose there exist two instances of `Collects`:

```
instance Collects Int SomeType
instance Collects Char SomeType
```

so what instance should `empty` use here:

```
let result = empty :: SomeType
```

It can be either the first or the second one. But since we don't know which one to use it's ambiguous.

Comment: The quote says "we cannot guarantee" because maybe everywhere `empty` appears, it gets an explicit signature with the element type `:: Collects Int SomeType => SomeType` or `empty` is an argument to an `insert` with an element of known type. But the compiler won't take that risk, unless you set `AllowAmbiguousTypes`.